# Warning: Received the string `true` for the boolean attribute `hidden`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an accordion which opens and closes on click. All my data is stored in .json file. Even though boolean values are changing (I checked by console), it is not working. Also my console gives the following warning: *Warning: Received the string `true` for the boolean attribute `hidden`. Although this works, it will not work as expected if you pass the string "false". Did you mean hidden={true}?*
When I pass manually 'false' or 'true' to 'hidden', it shows content of accordion accordingly. I work with Gatsby.
Here is my code:

```
handleClick(e, id) {
    const itemIndex = this.props.jobOpenings.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
    const item = { ...this.props.jobOpenings[itemIndex] };
    const items = [...this.props.jobOpenings];

    item.isCollapsed = !this.props.jobOpenings[itemIndex].isCollapsed;
    item.isAriaExpanded = !this.props.jobOpenings[itemIndex].isAriaExpanded;
    item.isHidden = !this.props.jobOpenings[itemIndex].isHidden;

    items[itemIndex] = item;
    this.setState({ items: items });
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        items: [...this.props.jobOpenings]
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

render() {
    const items = this.props.jobOpenings;
    return (
        {
            items.map(item =>
                <div key={item.id}>
                    <button className="accordion-btn" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, item.id)} aria-label="Careers">
                        <span className="accordion-title" id={item.id} aria-expanded={items[item.id].isAriaExpanded}>{item.title}</span>
                        <span className="accordion-icon" aria-hidden="true"> {items[item.id].isCollapsed ? <Plus /> : <Minus />} </span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="accordion-content" hidden={items[item.id].isHidden}>
                        <p className="accordion-content-title">Job Description</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requirementOne}</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requirementTwo}</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requirementThree}</p>
                        <p className="accordion-content-title">Required Skills</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requiredSkills}</p>
                        <p className="accordion-content-title">Required Experience</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requiredExperience}</p>
                        <p className="accordion-content-title">Preferred Education</p>
                        <p>•  {item.requiredEducation}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `.json` as well?

Comment: @FerranBuireu "jobOpenings": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "isCollapsed": true,
            "isAriaExpanded": false,
            "isHidden": true,
            "title": "Test",
            "requirementOne": "Test",
            "requirementTwo": "Test",
            "requirementThree": "Test",
            "requiredSkills": "Test",
            "requiredExperience": "Test",
            "requiredEducation": "Test"
        }, .... ]

Comment: This is not related to your problem but I doubt your code will ever work as expected: in your `render()` method you initialize `const items = this.props.jobOpenings;` and that is never going to change (unless a different value is sent by a parent component); it should be `const items = this.state.items;`

Comment: @secan it does work, yes! thank you! however, now it opens when i click on (let's say A) and closes only when clicking on B. and i want it to open and close on click by A separately, and on B separately.

Comment: More in general, I think you should decouple the jobOpenings data (such as title and requirements) from the visualization information (such as `isCollapsed`, `isHidden`, etc.). The job openings data are "static" and can be stored in a JSON file, the visualization is dinamic and belongs to the state of the component rendering the data.

Comment: @nlstmn that is because you have the very same issue in your `handleClick()` function: you keep referring to `this.props.jobOpenings` when what you really should refer to is the current state stored in `this.state.items`